# python aiorpc: "ImportError: cannot import name 'RPCServer' from 'aiorpc.server'"

Tags: python, rpc

I'm looking for a python rpc lib and I found this https://pypi.org/project/aiorpc/ I ran the very first server example in the docs and I got an error:

> "ImportError: cannot import name 'RPCServer' from 'aiorpc.server'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiorpc/server.py)

" How do I go about debugging this? Not sure if this is a bug in the library, or if I'm  using it incorrectly

Comment: Did you get any errors when you tried to install it? (`pip install aiorpc`)

Comment: @NirAlfasi no errors, nope

Comment: did you figure it out or decided to use a different lib?

Comment: @NirAlfasi I'm now using aiomas. The library in question looks like spam to me :)

Comment: "spam" is a bit harsh but I agree that it's not well maintained. Many open source projects are getting neglected because they don't have enough people to support/maintain them...

Answer (score 1):

1. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/choleraehyq/aiorpc/issues/24) for it since Oct 2020
2. The [readme](https://github.com/choleraehyq/aiorpc) states that:

> Note aiorpc is under development, should not be considered to have a
> stable API.

3. The Pypi page states that it supports Python 3.5 while you're on 3.9 which may also contribute to the issue (see screenshot below)

[image]

**Bottom line**: You may have to find a different library to work with